# Подключить php файл, используя js

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Нужен аналог include. php файл должен подключаться по js запросу. load, а также ajax не помогают, так как при прямом обращение к файлу нету всех тех переменых, которые нужны при обработке php файла. Возможно ли вообще то, что я задумал?

Если переделывать файл - займёт много времени. Придётся с заного задавать кучу переменных.
Файл может быть вставлен во много количество мест, так что использовать include и скрывать результат тоже не вариант. страница загнётся.
Буду рад любым вариантам.

Comment: О каких переменных вы говорите?  Как должен загружаться php файл?  Что будет делать этот файл?

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли вообще то, что я задумал?

Нет. У JS нету прямого доступа к PHP, т.к. первый находится на клиенте, а второй на сервере. У JS есть доступ только к тому, что отдаёт сервер (в данном случае PHP).